# How to configure sidekiq&redis without using docker-compose for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, port, sidekiq

I want to implement sidekiq to my rails app. I successfully create image and container. But when i try to execute job container in application can't find redis. How i can connect my-app container (which has it's own IP:port) with redis container (which has it's own IP:port).

I think the problem hides in sidekiq.rb. But I'm not sure

```
sidekiq_config = { url: "<container url>" }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config
end
```

I want to run 2 containers : `my-app` & `redis`. In `my-app` container sidekiq should know how to ping `redis` container.

PS
My  ̶r̶e̶l̶i̶g̶i̶o̶n̶ mentor do not allow me use docker-compose so it's pretty tricky

Comment: How does your container url look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that we can easily connect 2 containers with docker by using `--link`

```
sudo docker run --name my-application --link my-redis-container:redis
```

This [Link](https://www.ionos.com/community/hosting/redis/using-redis-in-docker-containers/) was helpful for me. And here we don't actually need to use docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Considering your statement:

> ...your app (which has its own IP:Port) with Redis container (which has it's own IP:Port).

You might want to check how what your `"<container url>"` looks like. For more insight, this is how I suggest it looks like:

## config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/0' }
end
```

Then right in your `application.rb` define the queue adapter as sidekiq

## config/application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Also, note that sidekiq looks for the configuration file in `config/sidekiq.yml` and if the file is present it starts with the defined configuration. So check if you have config set. It might be the main issue you have as you didn't give enough clue on what you have done.

## config/sidekiq.yml

```
---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
:timeout: 30
:queues:
  - [low_priority, 1]
  - [high_priority, 2] # high priority
```

For more insight how you use Redis with Sidekiq, kindly check https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis